# prove limit doesn't exist $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2}$

Tags: limits

I need to show that limit doesn't exist:

$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)x^2y^2}$

How can I show it?

Comment: Try two curves that gives different results

Comment: By considering sequences $(x_n, y_n)_n$ converging to $(0,0)$. Have you tried out some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(2x^2)}{(2x^2)x^2x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(2x^2)}{2x^6}=\infty.$$

Comment: That limit exists and is infinite.

Comment: The OP wrote “I need to show that limit doesn't exist”. That made me think that the OP meant a *real* limit.

Comment: Perhaps that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Take $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},y=\frac{1}{n^2}$$, then your limit is infinity.

Answer (score 0):

First, not that for $xy\ne 0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)}&=\frac{2\sin^2(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)}\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2\times \left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}\right)\tag1
\end{align}$$

The first term on the right-hand side of $(1)$, $\left(\frac{\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}\right)^2$, tends to $1$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ However, the second term, $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2y^2}$ tends to $+\infty$ since

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2}\ge \frac{1}{x^2}\to \infty$$

Therefore, we see that

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)}=\infty$$

Comment: Hi @alonaK Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Please feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Polar coordinates:

$\dfrac{1-\cos (r^2)}{r^6 \cos^2 t \sin^2 t}= 4\dfrac{1- \cos (r^2)}{r^6 \sin^2(2t)}.$

$2t \not = kπ$, $k=0,1,2,3$.

Fix $t$, and consider

$A \dfrac{1-\cos (r^2)}{r^6}$, with $A=\dfrac{4}{\sin^2(2t)}>0$.

$A \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1-\cos (r^2)}{r^6}=\infty.$